# How to fix 'Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String)' error?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, settext

I am a beginner at Java and coding. I don't know if this problem is occurring because I forgot something in the code or something is not correct in the code.

I have already tried looking through all the questions on Stack Overflow that are similar to my question and none of them helped me. I've been doing trial and error but still cannot fix it.

``````
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class JLabel {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        String myTitle = "Blank Frame";
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test");
     `````
        label1.setText("Test Text");
     `````
        myFrame.setTitle(myTitle);
        myFrame.setTitle(900,600);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
``````

At **'label1.setText("Test Text");'** is where the problem is. My goal for this code is to create a window that has some text in it. Hopefully, the fix is simple and not as complicated as many codes.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you have documented locally. However, mine fails to compile on `myFrame.setTitle(900,600);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your class, as that's an already existing class that you're using.  Creating a `LJabel` object will now create an instance of your object rather than the `java.swing` equivalent.

You didn't add the label to the frame.

```
myFrame.add(label1);
```

You're also calling `setTitle()` twice when I believe you meant to call `setSize()`.

This code works for me :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    String myTitle = "Blank Frame";
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test");
    label1.setText("Test Text");
    myFrame.add(label1);
    myFrame.setTitle(myTitle);
    myFrame.setSize(900,600);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: although this helped some, it still shows the same 'cannot resolve method' thing

Answer (score 0):

remove the  ````` things and you are fine...
or are these just for the example?

Comment: the ````` things are to provide which line is needing the fix

Comment: provide a real example, without compile-errors. You said, you are a beginner, so the false characters are an error. Remove all lines, and add them one by one. When does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

This message tells you that the method `setText` is not define in your defined class `JLabel` which is not equivalent of `JLabel` class available in `Swing` packages.
Rename your own defined class `JLabel` to `JLabelTest` for example.
Also, remove this line `myFrame.setTitle(900,600);`, the definition of `setTitle` doesn't allow those parameters, and replace it with `myFrame.setSize(900,600);`
Your complete code should be:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class JLabelTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        String myTitle = "Blank Frame";
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test");

        label1.setText("Test Text");

        myFrame.setTitle(myTitle);
        myFrame.setSize(900,600);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(label1); // to display the label
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Just an personal advise; try to read very carefully your tutorial and understand how Swing works step by step.

Hope this will help you.